# Error getting value from EditText

Tags: java, android

For some reason I can't get text from EditText with OnClickListener for my button. I want to get these values and place them into data[] and then transfer it to my main activity. For some reason it breaks on if statement in onClick() method. I've checked all the ids of layout elements and that's not the problem.

Here is the source code for my fragment:

```
package com.xivi0n.materialcalculator;



import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

RadioGroup rd;
CheckBox cb;
Button calculate;
OnHeadlineSelectedListener sendData;
private EditText yEditText;
private EditText xEditText;
private RadioGroup type;

float data[] = new float[6];

public FirstFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(float data[]);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        sendData = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener)context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    rd = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.isolationOptions);
    cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.isolationCB);
    xEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.xValue);
    yEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.yValue);
    type = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.typeOf);
    calculate = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
    cb.setOnClickListener(this);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v==cb) {
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            rd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            rd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } else if (v==calculate){
        if ((xEditText.getText().toString()!="") && (yEditText.getText().toString()!="")){
            data[0] = (float)1;
            data[1] = Float.parseFloat(xEditText.getText().toString());
            data[2] = Float.parseFloat(yEditText.getText().toString());
            data[3] = (float) type.indexOfChild(getActivity().findViewById(type.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
            if (cb.isChecked()){
                data[4] = (float)1;
                data[5] = (float) rd.indexOfChild(getActivity().findViewById(type.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
            } else {
                data[4] = (float)0;
                data[5] = (float)0;
            }
            sendData.onArticleSelected(data);
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid input, check all the parameters!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals` to compare strings.

Instead of `((xEditText.getText().toString()!= ""))` use `(!(xEditText.getText().toString().equals(""));` as the condition of if statement.

Comment: That is not the problem, if v==cb it does the work i want to. Problem appears after I click the button which means there must be problem with something else in that if (v.equals(calculate)){..} statement.

Comment: What are you expecting and what is happening?

Comment: `xEditText.getText().toString()!="") && (yEditText.getText().toString()!=""` this line doesn't work for some reason. It crashes application here.

Comment: use `.equals` to compare strings. And crashes? You should edit your answer and post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on the id of the view:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.isolationCB:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.calculateButton:
        //do something else
    }
}
```